# Android MVVM 2 ViewModels Sharing 1 Repository with LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-mvvm, mutablelivedata

I have a question regarding MVVM pattern with Repository.

- I have an activity that hosts 2 fragments. Let's call them `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`.
- These 2 fragments have their own viewModels like `viewModelA` and `viewModelB`.
- I also have a repository class that serves only local data. No network request. Just a MutableList.
- `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` observe their respective viewModel through LiveData.

```
//FragmentA Observes viewModelA
viewModelA.cartContent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { content ->

})
```

```
// ViewModelA exposes cartContent
val cartContent: LiveData<MutableList<Item>> = repository.getContent()
```

```
// Repository
private val contentRepository = mutableListOf<Item>()
fun getContent() : LiveData<MutableList<Item>> {
  val data = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item>>()
  data.value = contentRepository
  return data
}
.
.
.
```

Now, both viewModels are making changes on the repository that keeps a MutableList. I would like to know if it is possible to observe the changes on the repository that is done by the other viewModel. If so, how?

To be more clear, I want `viewModelA` to know when `viewModelB` modifies the list in repository. Can `viewModelA` observe data in repository so that when `viewModelB` modifies it, it propagates to `viewModelA` as well?

*I would rather not use a shared viewModel. I would also prefer to solve it with observing LiveData rather than using interfaces*

Thank you

Comment: is `Fragment B` open when `FragmentA` is opened?

Comment: `FragmentA` is always open. `FragmentB` may or may not be opened. But, If `FragmentB` is opened, `FragmentA` is opened for sure as well.

Comment: Can't you just observe the repository LiveData from both view models?

Comment: That's exactly what i am asking :) To observe I need `viewLifecycleOwner ` and view model does not have it.

Comment: `Transformations.switchMap` is what you are looking for. Have a read about it.

Comment: @artenson.art98 I did read it but I really can't see how I could apply it to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Repository
private val contentRepository = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>(Collections.emptyList())
fun getContent() : LiveData<List<Item>> = contentRepository

fun addContent(item: Item) {
    val list = ArrayList(contentRepository.value!!)
    list.add(item)
    contentRepository.value = Collections.unmodifiableList(list)
}

fun setContent(items: List<Item>) {
    contentRepository.value = Collections.unmodifiableList(ArrayList(items))
}
```

And

```
val cartContent: LiveData<List<Item>> = repository.getContent()
```

And

```
import androidx.lifecycle.observe

//FragmentA Observes viewModelA
viewModelA.cartContent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { content ->

}
```